# conditional deleting rows in a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have two matrices in R, the first one looks something like this:

```
a=matrix(c(1,0,1,0,1),nrow=5,ncol=1)
```

And the second one could look something like this:

```
b=matrix(c(0.5,0.3,-0.3,0.2,0.4),nrow=5,ncol=1)
```

I want to make a new vector/matrix from b conditional on the elements of a being equal to 1, i.e. only pick out elements of b, where elements of a are equal to one.

I tried something like this:

```
c=ifelse(a==1,b,0)
```

But instead of returning zeros, I just want it to delete the rows.

Thanks.

Comment: You could try: `c <- b[a == 1]`.

Comment: `b[a==1,,drop=FALSE]` might be more appropriate if you want to keep a matrix structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subset the rows of `b` conditioned on the rows of `a` being equal to 1 by using vector operations.

`b[a == 1, ]`

Comment: As I noted in a comment to the OP, this exact code does not generalise to a one column `b` matrix - you need `b[a==1,,drop=FALSE]` to make sure the result is not coerced to the simplest vector format. Introducing a two column matrix to the answer actually complicates matters in this instance.

Comment: Point taken.  I removed the two column example.